# How to create custom error and notify messages

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I want to create custom error and notify messages, but i don't know which element should I use. In the message there should be icon and text I tried to use Label but don't know how to build custom label the one I need. Is there a resource on how to create a custom label or tip how to do it? Also label needs border and some effects.

Comment: do you want a custom error popup, or to show custom error codes in the flash debug version?

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the default `Alert` popup and add an icon.

From http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/07/21/setting-an-icon-in-an-alert-control/:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/07/21/setting-an-icon-in-an-alert-control/ -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
        layout="vertical"
        verticalAlign="middle"
        creationComplete="showAlert();"
        backgroundColor="white">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.CloseEvent;

            // Embed the error.png image.
            [Bindable]
            [Embed(source='assets/error.png')]
            private var Icon:Class;

            private var a:Alert;

            private function showAlert():void {
                var titleText:String = "WARNING";
                var messageText:String = "Are you sure you would like to erase the Internet?\\n\\nPress OK to continue, or Cancel to abort.";
                /* Display the Alert, show the OK and Cancel buttons,
                    and show an icon represented by the Icon binding. */
                a = Alert.show(messageText, titleText, Alert.OK | Alert.CANCEL, null, doClose, Icon);
            }

            private function doClose(evt:CloseEvent):void {
                // do nothing.
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:Button label="Launch Alert" click="showAlert();" />

</mx:Application>
```